# class file for android.security.identity.IdentityCredential not found

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx, android-biometric-prompt

As part of authentication in my app, I am trying to implement biometric authentication.

I did the required code changes as per documentation.

When building my application, I am facing the below build error.

> class file for android.security.identity.IdentityCredential not found

Please find the build.gradle file below.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vj.togetheron"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    //implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc03"

    // For Identity Credential APIs
    //implementation "androidx.security:security-identity-credential:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    //implementation "androidx.security:security-identity-credential:1.0.0-alpha01"
    //implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Please anyone inform what I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`android.security.identity.IdentityCredential` is available only starting from API level 30.

I've been able to resolve this error by setting `compileSdkVersion 30` in `build.gradle` for my main project **and all libraries** which are compiled from sources.

For some unknown reason when I set "compileSdkVersion 30" for the main project but one library still contains "compileSdkVersion 29" in its build.gradle, the android-29 sdk path is used for compiling the main project. :(

Comment: Save my hours. Thanks